# Remove Virus certificate attachments from Emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate, attachments, avg-antivirus

When I'm receiving emails from PC having AVG antivirus, it's coming with virus certificate attachment file, to prove that there is no virus inside the email. 
I want to remove all those certificate files from my emails, how can I do that?

Because showing that email has attachments is confusing me while doing search, etc...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So just to clarify - - You are only concerned about incoming emails from people who use avg anti-virus? Or are you yourself using avg and are concerned about the report attached when emails are sent out?

Comment: This is simple.  Disable the AVG Outlook add-on.  The AVG add-on does not provide a mechanic to remove their signature because its free advertising.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Incoming emails from people which having attachment file name _Certification_.txt. This file is generated by AVG AV, how Can I delete this file from my emails? currently I'm having more than 10000 emails having this file.